# issues with Jenkins start up on suse linux

Tags: jenkins

We have Jenkins installed on Suse linux.It was running fine till 2 days ago. Since yesterday, we are facing an issue. The jenkins service gets started but only for 1-2 secs and again stops. It looks like service is not getting started on port 80. We already have HTTP PORT configured on 80 and as such nothing has been changed in files. What could be possible reason ?
Here is log contentt:

```
Feb 15, 2014 7:07:49 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: System.getProperty("JENKINS_HOME")
Feb 15, 2014 7:07:52 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
Feb 15, 2014 7:07:52 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpListener

at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:229)
at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:181)
at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at Main._main(Main.java:273)
at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to listen on port 80
at winstone.HttpListener.getServerSocket(HttpListener.java:119)
at winstone.HttpListener.start(HttpListener.java:72)
at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:220)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
at winstone.HttpListener.getServerSocket(HttpListener.java:114)
... 10 more
```

Comment: You should check your logs. Also make sure you are root when starting Jenkins. This is mandatory for opening ports up to 1024.

Comment: Well, I have edited my question with the log. COuld you please see what could be the cause of this port error.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the log I can tell that it's exactly like I guessed in my comment.

It fails to start listening on the port (in your case 80):

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpListener
```

The cause for that is that you don't have the permission:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
```

This because ports up to 1024 can only be opened by the root user. You now have two options:

- Run Jenkins as root (I would not recommend this for security issues)
- Chose a port bigger than 1024. This is the prefered solution. You could then [add an iptables rule](https://serverfault.com/a/112798) to redirect port 80 to your chosen port.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We went with the first option of running jenkins as root. The issue got resolved but from last few days we are seeing issues with maven repository. Because we had given Jenkins root permission, we had to give maven also the root permission so that EAR files get copied to /var/lib/.m2 repository but to our astonishment maven is creating the .m2 repository on root level inside the root home at : </root>/root/.m2 .Also to add, sometimes the files are getting copied to /var/lib/.m2 and sometimes to root/.m2. Can you please help with some solution on it ?

Comment: Yes: Don't run it as root! Seriously! You can change the repository location in the [Maven settings](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) to your liking after that but don't run it as root.

Comment: Ok.On another note, we didn't change anything in settings.xml in maven and previously before (jenkins issue)it was copying to /var/lib . In fact I don't see this location defined anywhere in settings.xml. where is var/lib defined in settings.xml ?

Comment: My guess is that `/var/lib` is the home folder for the Jenkins default user (which usually is called "jenkins"). The default Maven repository is created in the home folder of the user which executes it.